# Detectar botão de voltar do smartphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Existe alguma forma de detectar quando o botão físico de voltar do *smartphone* é clicado?

Preciso disso para fechar um *modal*.

Pensei que pudesse existir um número correspondente como no teclado e usar o `event.which` para detectar, mas não encontrei.

Comment: Acho que isso é muito relativo, pq iPhones não possuem botão voltar, isso é mais andoid.

Comment: Sim, mas no android teria alguma forma pra fazer isso?

Comment: Está falando de apps? Em React Native existe o BackHandler, que detecta quando o botão voltar for pressionado.

Comment: Se for web, pode usar jquery mobile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087816/how-to-detect-if-the-back-button-is-pressed-in-mobile-phone

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é usar a API de histórico (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Quando você abrir o modal seria como se estivesse entrando em outra página, daí o botão voltar do android e também o do navegador irão conseguir voltar ao estado anterior quando acionados. Você não precisa saber o código do botão nem depende da existência dele, já que o browser também possui um.